# Java-Only JFrame is clickable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, always-on-top

I have a simple JFrame, and I want my JFrame always on top **and** I want, that only my Frame is clickable, so no other window can be clicked.

I know how my Frame is on Top

```
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

But I don't know how I to reach my second aim.

Comment: So, you want to hijack the user's desktop?

Comment: I don't think Java (i.e. Swing or JavaFX) will let you do exactly what you describe.  Even if they did I don't think you *should*.  Not unless you really want to annoy your users.  Perhaps you could tell us why you want to do this?  Have you considered switching you application into full-screen mode instead?  Have a look at `java.awt.GraphicsDevice.setFullScreenWindow()` and related methods.

Comment: I am writing an security programm, so, when you plug in an unregistered Usb-Stick, my Frame pop up, and you have to enter a pw to get acces to your usb-stick, or you cancel the connection.

Comment: It will be a security by obscurity program then - there is a bunch of ways to bypass any obstinate window that can't be easily blocked, the simplest being hotkey shortcuts. You cannot block all user interaction with a simple window. The best you can do is cover the whole screen, but still its pretty easy to get other windows in front of it (e.g. any program also opening an "always on top" window).

Comment: Without resorting to using something like Full Screen Exclusive mode, I doubt this would be particularly achievable, it would also be possible to circumvent thought the use of the ctrl+tab combination